# How to use .xls filter msofiledialogsaveas in ms access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use below  code which i found in msdn library. but dialog box does not show
and when i only use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) withApplication.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Addfilter Its give me error object doesnot support this property

```
Sub Main()

'Declare a variable as a FileDialogFilters collection.
Dim fdfs As FileDialogFilters

'Declare a variable as a FileDialogFilter object.
Dim fdf As FileDialogFilter

'Set the FileDialogFilters collection variable to
'the FileDialogFilters collection of the SaveAs dialog box.
Set fdfs = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Filters

'Iterate through the description and extensions of each
'default filter in the SaveAs dialog box.
For Each fdf In fdfs

    'Display the description of filters that include
    'Microsoft Excel files
    If InStr(1, fdf.Extensions, "xls", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Description of filter: " & fdf.Description
    End If
Next fdf
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Show` is a method of the `FileDialog` object, not the `FileDialogFilter`.

Comment: but how to show filedialogsaveas with .xls filter.its give me error object doesnot support when i use this code

Comment: dlgOpen.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls"

Comment: Set dlgOpen = FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)